# At HTML form tag why should I use GET method instead of POST?

Tags: html, forms, post, methods, get

I was studying HTML and I saw that when someone is making a form the safest method is POST. So why someone should choose GET method? And when we choose GET or POST method?

Comment: _“when someone is making a form the safest method is POST”_ - that is an absolute nonsense statement. GET vs POST has absolutely zero point zero to do with “safety”.

Comment: CBroe to be honest I read that on w3schools

Answer (score 0):

**GET** is used to view something **without** changing it. **POST** is used to change something. Suppose if you have a search page- it should use GET; but if you want to change password then POST is used.
One big reason is that Get requests can remain in browser history and it has length restrictions. On the other hand, POST requests are not cached and can't be bookmarked.

Comment: *GET is used to view something without changing it.* Wrong. You can very well use GET to change something and POST without changing it.